# Are the solutions of this two PDEs equal at the final time?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Consider the Cauchy problem given by

\begin{align}(1)
\begin{cases}
\partial_t u= -\partial_x [f(x)u],\;\; t\in [0,\|\Delta\|]\\
u(0,x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\|\Delta\|}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\|\Delta\|}}.
\end{cases}
\end{align}

I am trying to find out whether the latter is related in some way to the Fokker-Planck equation

\begin{align}(2)
\begin{cases}
\partial_t u= -\partial_x [f(x)u]+\frac{1}{2}\partial_{xx}u,\;\; t\in [0,\|\Delta\|]\\
u(0,x)=\delta(x),
\end{cases}
\end{align}

where $\|\Delta\|>0$.

If we let $f\equiv 0$ we have that the solution of $(1)$ is constant and equals the initial condition, on the other hand $(2)$ becomes the homogeneous heat equation, and its solution is given by the heat semigroup.

Then we have that for $t=\|\Delta\|$ the solution of $(1)$ and $(2)$ coincide.

I am wondering whether the latter holds also for the case in which $f$ is some well-behaved function, any idea?

EDIT:

Another example can be obtained by letting $f=1$, in that case $(1)$ becomes

\begin{align}(1)
\begin{cases}
\partial_t u= -\partial_x u,\;\; t\in [0,\|\Delta\|]\\
u(0,x)=\varphi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\|\Delta\|}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\|\Delta\|}},
\end{cases}
\end{align}
and the solution is given by $u(t,x)=\varphi(x-t)$ which at time $t=\|\Delta\|$ equals the density of a $N(\|\Delta\|,\|\Delta\|)$ r.v.

On the other hand $(2)$ becomes the Fokker-Planck equation of an Ito process given by $dX_t= dt+dB_t$ from where it's easy to see that at $t=\|\Delta\|$ again the solutions of $(1)$ and $(2)$ coincide.